# Delegate and event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have 2 forms.

Form1:

```
public partial class Panel1
    {
        public void ShowExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           .......
        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Panel2
{
        public delegate void ShowExportReport(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event ShowExportReport ShowExportClicked;

private void buttonExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
           if (ShowExportClicked != null)
            {
                ShowExportClicked(sender, new EventArgs());
            }                     

        }
}
```

When I click **button** -

```
button.Click = buttonExport_Click
```

How can I call **Panel1.ShowExport()** from **Panel2.buttonExport_Click**?

Comment: I want notice that your event is not thread-save. Copy event to local variable, then check on null then invoke.

Answer (score 2):

In the Panel1 you have to subscribe the event:

```
pnl2.ShowExportClicked += new ShowExportReport(ShowExport);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the handler for the event ShowExportClicked in Panel 1 class to the   Panel 2 class object.

```
     public partial class Panel1
        {
            Panel2 pnl2;
            public Panel1()
            {
               pnl2 = new Panel2();
               pnl2.ShowExportClicked += new ShowExportReport(ShowExport);    
            }

            public void ShowExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               .......
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont whant to this : pnl2.Show();

Comment: You can't do it! You need to be in a method or in the constructor to bind event to event handlers.

Comment: Procedural code cannot be on the 1st level of the class, maybe you meant to put them within a constrctor

Answer (score 0):

```
pnl2.ShowExportClicked += ShowExport;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your event on Form1. and listen to the event in Form2.

Form1:

```
public event EventHandler ShowExportChanged;

private void ShowExportChanged()
{
    var handler = ShowExportChanged;
    if(handler == null)
        return;

    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public void ShowExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ShowExportChanged();
}
```

Form2:

```
pnl1.ShowExportChanged+= new OnShowExportChanged(ShowExportChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call Panel1.ShowExport() from Panel2.buttonExport_Click?

By passing (only the necessary) information from form1 when instantiating form2.

Form1.cs:

```
void ShowForm2_Click()
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowExportClicked += ShowExport;
    form2.Show();
}
```

Now from Form2 you can simply call `ShowExport` on button click.